# Making complex data classes for Room library in Kotlin

Tags: android, sql, database, kotlin, android-room

I have some complex json String response from server. I'm trying to make similarly structured `data class` in Kotlin to work with the `Room` library.

My data looks like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "summary": {
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value",
      ...

    },
    "key": "value",
    "key": "value",
    "key": "value",
    "key": [
      "value",
      "value",
      "value"
    ],
    "key": false,
    "key": 0,
    "key": 2.5,
    "key": "2",
    "key": [
      {
         "value",
         "value",
         ...
      },
      {
         "value",
         "value",
         ...
      }
    ],
    "key": value
  }
}
```

How do I incorporate this into a data class in Room using Kotlin?

Until now I had been using simpler json data like so:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    {
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value",
      ...
    },
    {
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

For the above model, I was using something like this in Room:

```
@Entity(table_name = "table_name")
data class EntityName(
 val value1 : String?
 val value2 : String?
 @PrimaryKey val id : Int
)
```

How do I incorporate all those different types of possibilities and branches that might occur?

I do have a [structure](https://gist.github.com/SowingFiber/0eb02508162e9624626cd48df52ab831) for all the possible branches with me.

Comment: Your `josn` is not well formatted. Object should contain `key` -> `value`.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman, I have given the original structure as well for review. I might have made a mistake while making the dummy

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman , But I've been using exactly that for this app. That is how the app has been functioning for over a year now.

Comment: keys are fixed or dynamic?

Comment: arrays could be dynamic. But the outermost keys are fixed. The structure link i put at the end of the answer has the current total number of keys, and it is not going to change from that for a while. Arrays, inside those keys, may increase though.